# CSS Minification

Tags: css, javascript, customization

Can someone help me understand the process that goes into employing CSS and JavaScript minification?

I am going to be having some development work done on my site to speed it up and I need to know how much work goes into minifying CSS so I don't get taken advantage of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally very little. There are plenty of automated systems for minifying both JS and CSS, and in all likelihood your developer will use one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Charles. I have been considering using Autoptimize-https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/ would this be a plugin you have had experience with or could recommend?

Comment: For CSS I like http://cssnano.co/
For JS I like http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/

Comment: Hye Charles,

Thanks for the recommendations. 

Do you have an opinion on implementing Lazy Loading or any experience using a plugin for this to help with image heavy pages?

I'm considering implementing Lazy Loading along with the minification  because my homepage is pretty heavy. 

If you have a chance please take a look and let me know what you think of the load time on the homepage.

Website - https://thebloggingbuddha.com/

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Hey Mike, I primarily do back end dev so I don't have a specific plugin to suggest. I do strategy and UX though, and through that lens, my suggestion is to avoid lazy loading. In my opinion, and it's just my opinion, you'll get better traction spreading content out across multiple pages than putting it all on one page. Just a few of the many reasons are: people will only scroll so far before they stop reading, smaller pages load faster, and more pages gives Google more to index so improves your overall rank. Plus you can monetize (sorry, dirty word) better than with single monolithic pages.

Comment: Hey Charles, Thanks so much for your advice. I appreciate your time and perspective. Enjoy the rest of your week. Thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome. If you think my answer was helpful please mark it as the correct answer and upvote it so the next person along can know to use it. - C